# Passing a login from one script to another

Tags: php, authentication

I have a script named `essay.php`. Its task is to provide an interface for writing essays. When student clicks the single submit on the form, the essay is to be saved to `essay.docu` file inside a `/var/essays/<login_name>` directory. For example, if login is `istvan111` the essay is to be saved to `/var/essays/istvan111` directory. If login is `anika121` the essay is to be saved to `/var/essays/anika121` directory. This `essay.php` script itself does not provide user with functionality to specify his login. Instead, another script named `logingui.php` is used. This script stores logins and password in a simple text file. Now, I need to make `essay.php` to know which login was selected in `logingui.php` and use it as the current login.

So far I have come up with only one solution which I think is pretty unserious. I made `logingui.php` to write selected login to a text file named after the value of `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`. After that `logingui.php` redirects to `essay.php`, which, in turn, reads the login from the text file previosly created by `logingui.php`. Now `essay.php` knows which login is current.

Is this a good approach to solving the problem of letting one script know which login was selected by another script?

Comment: Share your relavant `PHP` script with us so we can see what you have tried so far

Comment: Hello, you should really take a look at `PHP Sessions` - the solution for all your problems. :) https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_sessions.htm A bit older reference, but still okay I think.

Comment: Hello. Both scripts are independent from each other and so have different session variables.

Comment: But they *aren't* independent of each other, the second one depends on the first, which is why they should share the session. If you are going to cache, cache the sessionid. Also you aren't saying you are writing the user credentials in plain text are you? Once your user has authenticated you should not need those again, you just need to re-check the authorization and that the session hasn't expired. There are a number of serious security issues with the way you are doing this now.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use a php session. Check the official doc: http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php

By the way, storing your password in clear is not recommended (at all). You should use a password hash, but that's another question.

Comment: The problem is that session variables set in `logingui.php` are not visible to `essay.php`.

Comment: Session variables are made for this kind of need. Did you use session_start() on each script ?